# HTML - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons next to each other Trying to pass two variables in a function when using "onclick"

When I had one variable it works...I tried to add another and got the error.

Guess Im doing it wrong....I hate character escaping :(?

```
var proceed = 'true';
var reject = 'false';
var file = '<button id="submitButton" onclick="myController.warningsSubmit(\''value + '\',\'' + proceed + '\')" type="button">Submit</button><button id="rejectButton" onclick="myController.warningsSubmit(\''value + '\',\'' + reject + '\')" type="button">Reject</button>';


warningsSubmit : function(value, flag){   
        //alert("submit button pressed: " + value);
        steal.dev.log("submit button pressed : " + value + " submit button Flag : " + flag);
    },
```

Comment: Get rid of the single quote marks on the function calling args on line three.

Comment: The second to last line looks good.

Comment: @www139 Thanx dude....silly mistake on my part...

Comment: lol, next time you have this problem, just take a break and come back later. Your mind will be clearer and able to figure it out without going to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `plus` before both `value` variables.